# Convert two columns to json

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, json

I have a json column with a json array in the form of

`[{key : "key", value : "value"}, {key : "key2", value : "value2"}]`

that I wish to convert to a new form

`{"key" : "value", "key2" : "value2"}`.

I can use the following query to get rows with `key` column and `value` column

`SELECT json_array_elements(somejson)->'key', json_array_elements(somejson)->'value' FROM temp;`

However I can't seem to come up with a way to convert that to a nice key-value JSON object. Since I'm on 9.3, I can't use `json_object` or `json_build_object` either.

Comment: Short answer: update, doing this with 9.3 will be painful at best.

Comment: Thanks, that's what it seemed like, but I thought there might be some trick I hadn't considered, since I'm not primarily a DBA.

Comment: You can probably do it with string concatenation, but ... ugh. I don' t recommend it. json support continues to mature, so you'll often find cases where "gee, I wish I could do X" is solved in a newer version. There's a backport of the 9.5 json enhancements to 9.4, but not 9.4 to 9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would have been a lot faster and easier with 9.4, but it's doable with 9.3 in simple situations.

```
SELECT 
('{' ||       -- Opening brace for the JSON object
string_agg(   -- Get all the key/value pairs together in the same string
concat_ws(':', '"' || a || '"', b || ''), ',') || '}')::json -- Concatenate values to "key" : "value" format

FROM (
-- Extract the key and value from each array element
SELECT json_array_elements(myjson)->'key' a, 
json_array_elements(myjson)->'value' b FROM temp) AS FOO;
```

Not fun, but thankfully this is a one-time thing.

This can't be used to update a table, but you can create a temporary table and insert the values there first.

Comment: can you please share the 9.4 or say 9.6 version as well?

Comment: There's probably a direct bytecast from 9.4 onwards, or at least a conversion function between them.